# CodeIgniter + omnipay installation

Tags: codeigniter, ci-merchant

I have used ci-merchant before but from everything see that the "V2" of it is now omnipay. I use codeigniter and i'm struggling to get even the example to work.

I have installed omnipay no problems and in my controller have the following:

```
use Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;
class Homepage extends BC_basecontroller {

public function index()
{
    $gateway = GatewayFactory::create('PayPal_Express');
    $gateway->setUsername('adrian');
    $gateway->setPassword('12345');
}
}
```

Which is the example here: https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay

However I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory' not found in......
```

Does anyone know how to get it to work in CI?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you installed Omnipay, but you need to use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to load the classes before you can use them.

So following the [Omnipay installation instructions](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay#installation), add this to a `composer.json` file in your root directory:

```
{
    "require": {
        "omnipay/omnipay": "*"
    }
}
```

Then install the files:

```
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar update
```

Now, if you are using CodeIgniter you will need to set it up to include the composer autoloader. Basically, just add this line to the top of your `index.php` file:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

There is also a tutorial on using Composer with CodeIgniter here which you may find helpful: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks for this - I finally got it working. It was erroring due to permission not the code but the server error messages don't mention that.

Your message did however lead me to know I was implementing it correctly!

Comment: Hey, I'm having this same issue. Can you identify what the permission issue was and how you fixed it?

Comment: Hi dan - when I run composer update on my local host it resets the vendors folder permissions to no longer work. I have to right click on that folder -> change permissions for say 'everyone' to read/write and apply to all sub folders, then it worked.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to just `rm -rf vendor/` and then re-run `composer update` too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and fixed it by loading `vendor/autoload.php` before `application/core/CodeIgniter.php`