# How to use omnipay for implementing online payment with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, omnipay

I am trying to using omnipay for implementing online payment.

I have read several article on this topic. Also, I have read the omnipay documentation on github. But I could not understand, how can I implement it ?

Because, The documentation is not clear to me.

Is there any good article on it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently, I have faced this problem. After trying some days later, I have success. I will mention those steps as:

Step-1: At first install composer in your system. Follow this link for composer->http://getcomposer.org/

Step-2: Install Omnipay in your system according to this instruction https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay#installation

Step-3: Create a composer.json file in your root directory. And paste this code in it

```
 {
    "require": {
        "omnipay/omnipay": "*"
   }
}
```

Step-4: Then install curl in your system using this command

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Step-5: Update composer using:

```
 php composer.phar update
```

Step-6: Include the composer autoloader. Just add this line to the top of your index file file:

```
require_once __DIR__./vendor/autoload.php';
```

Step-7: If it not works provide the 0777 file permission.

```
  sudo chmod -R 0777 your_directory
```

Even

```
   rm -rf vendor/
```

and then re-run composer update too.

I hope this will work.For any further problem follow:

1. http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter
2. [CodeIgniter + omnipay installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081800/codeigniter-omnipay-installation)

I hope you will success like as me. 
Warning: Do not miss to add the ominipay controller and library to your controller and library.

Comment: Following this process, Successfully I have used omnipay.
But, I don't know, How to test the transaction.

Comment: For testing your account you have to create an account in www.sandbox.paypal.com

One for business and another for personal.