# Error in installing omnipay in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, omnipay

I'm trying to add omnipay in CodeIgniter (version 2.2.4) I followed the instructions in installing composer using this link:https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter/

but I'm having this error:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Omnipay\Common\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Class '\Omnipay\PayPal Express\Gateway' not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testserver\vendor\omnipay\common\src\Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory.php:105
    Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory->create('PayPal Express')
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\testserver\vendor\omnipay\common\src\Omnipay\Omnipay.php(103): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\testserver\application\controllers\Test.php(18): Omnipay\Omnipay::__callStatic('create', Array)
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\testserver\application\controllers\Test.php(18): Omnipay\Omnipay::create('PayPal Express')
    #4 [internal function]: Test->Pay()
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\testserver\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(360): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\testserver\index.php(203): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
    #7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testserver\vendor\omnipay\common\src\Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory.php on line 105
```

I already followed the suggestions from this post([CodeIgniter + omnipay installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081800/codeigniter-omnipay-installation)) but none of their suggestion is working for me.

I'm using codeigniter 2.2.4 and apache 5.4.19

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it. 
I have found that there could be collision of `FCPATH . 'vendor'` autoloading and APPPATH . 'core' class autoloading. If you try to extend your controller from `CI_` or `MY_` prefixed core class I am sure that would work. In other hand, if you try to use core class that doesn't start with `CI_` or `MY_` or whatever you configured you couldn't find wanted class from vendor direcory.

I played around and found that if you would change the code used in config file for autoloading core classes it works. 
You could use

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
}
```

or

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT)) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

I swapped that file for this one:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT)) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
});
```

Just tested and it is working.

### Here is all process for those needs it step by step:

**1.** Download omnipay to root/vandor directory. If you don't have other vendor dependencies, do this with newly created `composer.json` file located next to `index.php` file with next code:

```
    {
        "require": {
            "omnipay/omnipay": "~2.0"
        }
    }
```

**2.** Navigate console to root folder of your project that also include newly created json file.

**3.** Start command `composer install`

**4.** Include composer autoload file before application boot. One way for doing this is near the end of the `index.php` file, just **before** line

```
    require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

, put next code:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

**5.** At the end of `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` file, put this snippet to use core classes as well:

```
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
            if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT)) {
                include $file;
            }
        }
    });
```

**6.** In your controller at the beginning of the file before class is defined use needed vendor classes:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    use \Omnipay\Omnipay;
    use \Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;

    class Test extends Back_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index()
        {
            var_dump(new Omnipay);
            var_dump(new GatewayFactory);
        }
    }
```