# Integrating omnipay with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, omnipay

I just installed omnipay/paypal with composer on my codeIgniter development website. I have read a lot of articles but none seems to point me in the right direction of appropriately using Omnipay with codeigniter, all the dependencies are foxing me and I just don't know where to start. Any article with an example omnipay CI implementation would do thank you.

Comment: Find something usefull [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424255/error-in-installing-omnipay-in-code-igniter/32425877#32425877).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can get the dependencies working and loading (usually via composer, although have a look at Tpojka's link for some issues related to autoloading composer packages in CI), there is nothing special about interfacing to Omnipay via any framework rather than any other framework.

Each type of omnipay gateway is a little bit different, so if you have some more specific questions to ask, backed up by a little bit of code (I tried "this" and I got "that error") then we can probably help out a bit more.

All of the examples in the omnipay gateway documentation are generic, that is they should work on any framework. There are no examples specific to CI.